# 'CSPv2.frmMain.pos.X' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#

`CSPv2.frmMain.pos.X` is inaccessible due to its protection level.
I used `struct` in my code and made an array of it.
When I call the array, I can't call it's like a `struct`.

```
 struct pos
    {
        string name;
        int X;
        int Y;
    }
    private void tabsFunc2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pos[,] arrpos=new pos[7,18];
        for (int i=0; i <7; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<18;j++)
                { 
                    arrpos[i,j].X=105 + 109*i;
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the variables in your `struct` `public`

```
struct pos 
{
    public string name;
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```